# renderizar un grafico pygal en una Qlabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, pygal

Buenos dias estoy tratando de mostrar un grafico en una qlabel con pixmap y pygal, sin embargo no funciona me lanza un error qn QPixmap

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSvg
import pygal
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Principal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("1.ui",self)

        svg_widget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget()

        bar = pygal.Histogram()
        bar.add("Tabla", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
        data = bar.render()
        svg_widget.load(data)

        pixi = QPixmap.fromImage(svg_widget)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixi)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    p.resize(900,600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no muestras  `svg_widget`  directamente en vez de usar un `QLabel`?

Comment: @FJSevilla, se me hace mas facil manejar directamente el label que el svg_widget, ademas de que como la interfaz la estoy realizando con el QTdesigner no encuentro directamente el svg_widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres obtener de la data que retorna el método `render()` de pygal debes usar QSvgRenderer:

```
import pygal
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSvg, uic


class Principal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("1.ui",self)

        hist = pygal.Histogram()
        hist.add('Wide bars', [(5, 0, 10), (4, 5, 13), (2, 0, 15)])
        hist.add('Narrow bars',  [(10, 1, 2), (12, 4, 4.5), (8, 11, 13)])
        data = hist.render()

        svg_render = QtSvg.QSvgRenderer(self)
        svg_render.load(data)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(svg_render.viewBox().size())
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
        svg_render.render(painter)
        painter.end()

        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    p.resize(900,600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Otra solución es seguir usando QSvgWidget, pero como señalas en los comentarios no aparece dentro de las opciones de Qt Designer, asi que en general si deseas usar un widget que no se muestra como opción la solución es promover el widget. Para promover un widget los pasos son los siguientes:

#### 1. Arrastra un item que sea cercano a la clase que deseas promover, en el caso de QSvgWidget el más cercano es widget:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 2. Haz click derecho, y en el menu selecciona la opción *promote to..*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 3. En los campos *Promote Class Name* coloca QSvgWidget y en *Header File* coloca PyQt5/QtSvg, presiona el boton *Add* y despues el boton *Promote*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo anterior genera el siguiente ui:

**1.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QSvgWidget" name="widget" native="true"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QSvgWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>PyQt5/QtSvg</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Con lo anterior ya puedes usar el QSvgWidget directamente:

```
import pygal
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSvg, uic


class Principal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("1.ui",self)

        hist = pygal.Histogram()
        hist.add('Wide bars', [(5, 0, 10), (4, 5, 13), (2, 0, 15)])
        hist.add('Narrow bars',  [(10, 1, 2), (12, 4, 4.5), (8, 11, 13)])
        data = hist.render()
        self.widget.load(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    p.resize(900,600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```